# DB error: no such table while importing

Tags: import

When importing, we get this error:

```
/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(192): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such table", -18, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed\n                 ...")
#3 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-18, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed\n                 ...")
#4 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -18, 16, (Array:2), "UPDATE civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed\n                 ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1907): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-18, NULL, NULL, "UPDATE civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed\n                 ...", "1146 ** Table 'xxx_civicrm.civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd356747799314...")
#7 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1012): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("UPDATE civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed\n                 ...")
#9 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1211): DB_common->execute(913, (Array:3))
#10 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser.php(738): DB_common->query("UPDATE civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed\n                 ...", (Array:3))
#11 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php(1944): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser->updateImportRecord("457", (Array:1))
#12 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php(1024): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->processMessage((Array:5), "_status", 1)
#13 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser.php(209): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser_Contact->import("4", (Array:5), NULL)
#14 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/ImportJob.php(249): CRM_Contact_Import_Parser->run("civicrm_import_job_a8e141751115f41cd3567477993145ed", (Array:2), 8, 1, "_id", "_status", "4", "cc85ebf7d841fd9aeb8129e3e6e63479", 2000, NULL, 30, NULL, "18")
#15 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Import/Form/Preview.php(298): CRM_Contact_Import_ImportJob->runImport(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview))
#16 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(490): CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview->postProcess()
#17 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(160): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#18 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(61): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next", "Next")
#19 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next")
#20 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Import_Form_Preview), "next")
#21 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(349): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#22 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#23 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#24 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#25 /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1392): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#26 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#27 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#28 /wp-includes/plugin.php(465): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#29 /wp-admin/admin.php(253): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#30 {main}
```

It doesn't occur every time, but if the import is 2-3K+ records (it is only external ID plus another field) then it fails more often. The same import can be run again and be successful :/ So there is not much consistency to this. When the error does start, it the issue get worse and worse where most imports fail. If we let the system sit and come back say the next day, it isn't as bad.

Civi 5.13.4